# delete row in googlesheet using googlesheetapi

Tags: google-sheets-api

I want to delete a row using rowno in googlesheet using googlesheetv4 api.
Can anybody provide me a sample code for this? I have created a method for delete row
public void deleteRow() {

```
    BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest content = new BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest();
    Request request = new Request();
    request.setDeleteDimension(new DeleteDimensionRequest().setRange(new DimensionRange().setDimension("D30:D31")));

    List<Request> requests = new ArrayList<Request>();
    requests.add(request);
    content.setRequests(requests);
    System.out.println(content.getRequests());

    try {
        service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(IConstant.SPREADSHEET_ID, content);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

to delete row in google Sheet using google Sheet v4 api we have to set start index and end index and also sheet Id 
see the example below

```
public void deleteRow(Integer StartIndex, Integer EndIndex) {
        Spreadsheet spreadsheet = null;
        try {
            spreadsheet = service.spreadsheets().get(GoogleExcelFileUtil.SPREASHEET_ID).execute();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest content = new BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest();
        Request request = new Request();
        DeleteDimensionRequest deleteDimensionRequest = new DeleteDimensionRequest();
        DimensionRange dimensionRange = new DimensionRange();
        dimensionRange.setDimension("ROWS");
        dimensionRange.setStartIndex(StartIndex);
        dimensionRange.setEndIndex(EndIndex);

        dimensionRange.setSheetId(spreadsheet.getSheets().get(0).getProperties().getSheetId());
        deleteDimensionRequest.setRange(dimensionRange);

        request.setDeleteDimension(deleteDimensionRequest);

        List<Request> requests = new ArrayList<Request>();
        requests.add(request);
        content.setRequests(requests);

        try {
            service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(GoogleExcelFileUtil.SPREASHEET_ID, content).execute();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            dimensionRange = null;
            deleteDimensionRequest = null;
            request = null;
            requests = null;
            content = null;
        }
    }
```